# signature exception when generate and validating the same token

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, jwt

i have coded a jwt creator and when i create the token there is no problem. But when i receive it from header and check it Signature exception occurs what is wrong in the below code?

```
@Service
public class TokenManager {

    private static final int validity = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

    public String generateToken(String afId) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(afId)
                .setIssuer("www.asn.com")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + validity))
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean tokenValidate(String token) {
        return getUsernameToken(token) != null && !isExpired(token);
    }

    public String getUsernameToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = getClaims(token);
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean isExpired(String token) {
        Claims claims = getClaims(token);
        return claims.getExpiration().before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    private Claims getClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody(); // SIGNATURE EXCEPTİON occurs
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely the _signature exception_ is thrown because something is wrong with the JWT. This could be the _key_ used for signing (or checking, is this the same still?) or something else is wrong with the token all together. Is it possible to update the post and show the `Claims` code as well?

Comment: Actually the claims code is from io.jsonwebtoken.Claims and this a java library. But when i debug the secret key yes it changes every request how can i keep it? Is adding static final a good approach?

Comment: You could try to make it _static final_, provided the entire _TokenManager_ isn't rebuild on each request (also a bit rusty on Java, so it might need to be private as well, in combination with static final).
Static final for things that you don't want to change is always a good approach, it is what is says: a variable that can't be changed after initial declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
```

That works fine.